# A variable from 'Context' is reset after a reboot page

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a check if the user is an administrator (true or false). I use `createContext` to store this information. After user is logged as admin everything is fine the variable becomes true, but after reloading the page it comes back as false. I'm sure the problem is in `auth.hook.js`, I marked where exactly, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it.

auth.hook.js

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'


const storageName = 'userData'

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null)
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false)
  const login = useCallback((jwtToken, isAdmin) => {
    setToken(jwtToken)
    setAdmin(isAdmin)
    localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify({
      token: jwtToken
    }))
  }, [])


  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    setToken(null)
    setAdmin(false)
    localStorage.removeItem(storageName)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName))

    if (data && data.token) {
      login(data.token, admin) // <-- There some problem
    }
  }, [login])


  return { login, logout, token, admin }
}
```

AuthContext.js

```
function noop() { }

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  token: null,
  login: noop,
  logout: noop,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  admin: false,
})
```

App.js

```
  const { token, login, logout, admin } = useAuth()
  const isAuthenticated = !!token
  const routes = useRoutes(isAuthenticated)
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      token, login, logout, isAuthenticated, admin
    }}> 
      <Router>  
        <div className="app-container">
          {routes}
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where do you store if the user is admin or not? Given the code you gave the user will never be an admin...

Comment: @IgnacioElias to tell the truth, right now i store this information on local storage :( But idk, i think it is bad practice. I wanna store admin information on context, and on this version of code i tried to do this, but it doesn't work.